# Named scope with a belongs_to join in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models

```
class Faq < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :faq_type
end
```

and

```
class FaqType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :faqs
end
```

I'd like to make a student scope that only gets the FAQs with a FaqType name of "student"

I've tried many variations of

```
class Faq < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :faq_type

  scope :student, -> { joins(:faq_type).where('faq_type.name = ?', 'Student') }
end
```

None of which seems to work.

The general error message is something like..

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "faq_type"
SELECT "faqs".* FROM "faqs" INNER JOIN "faq_types" ON "faq_types"."id" = "faqs"."faq_type_id" WHERE (faq_type.name = 'Student')
```

Could anyone explain what's going on here, reading the docs http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope seems to suggest this is the right approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be you have missed this part

```
.where('faq_type.name = ?', 'Student') }
```

Student.name or something else. Please double check.